# query with CASE inside SUM not working

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I should sum up some time periods depending on begin and start date, and I used CASE inside SUM function. But query is not working, what is the problem?
Here is the query:

```
SELECT @TotalDaysInThisYear = COALESCE(SUM(
                                CASE
                                    WHEN t.DateFrom < @BeginOfTheYear AND t.DateTo >= @EndOfTheYear THEN DATEDIFF(day, @BeginOfTheYear, t.DateTo) + 1
                                CASE
                                    WHEN t.DateFrom >= @BeginOfTheYear AND t.DateTo <= @EndOfTheYear THEN t.Days
                                CASE
                                    WHEN t.DateFrom <= @EndOfTheYear AND t.DateTo > @EndOfTheYear THEN DATEDIFF(day, t.DateFrom, @EndOfTheYear) + 1
                                ELSE 0
                                END
    ),0) FROM Common.TravelAgency ta JOIN Common.Travel t ON ta.TravelAgencyId = t.TravelId
    WHERE UserId = @UserId;
```

Comment: Are you see any error or getting wrong output?Add more details

Comment: This is error I get: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'.
If I comment out all lines inside SUM, and instead of them just write t.Days, everything is working.

Comment: You only need `CASE` keyword once.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos xD I  looked over many examples but couldn't notice difference... Thanks.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos, Answer my question, I will accept it. Since you saw the problem first :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove extra `CASE` keywords

```
 SELECT @TotalDaysInThisYear = COALESCE(SUM(
                                    CASE
                                        WHEN t.DateFrom < @BeginOfTheYear AND t.DateTo >= @EndOfTheYear THEN DATEDIFF(day, @BeginOfTheYear, t.DateTo) + 1
                                        WHEN t.DateFrom >= @BeginOfTheYear AND t.DateTo <= @EndOfTheYear THEN t.Days
                                        WHEN t.DateFrom <= @EndOfTheYear AND t.DateTo > @EndOfTheYear THEN DATEDIFF(day, t.DateFrom, @EndOfTheYear) + 1
                                    ELSE 0
                                    END
        ),0) FROM Common.TravelAgency ta JOIN Common.Travel t ON ta.TravelAgencyId = t.TravelId
        WHERE UserId = @UserId;
```